# Nested Array in React Object

Tags: arrays, reactjs

How do I structure this to stop getting the cant read property map of undefined? The note Object itself looks like this.  I will need to repeat this for a secondary array tasks as well. The problem I'm running into with a lot of other examples is they are either class-based or mapping an array with an array. This should be easier I feel like, but I've tried 1000 things and none of them work.

```js
const notes = [
  { 
    id: noteId,
    note: noteText,
    notePostedBy: ''
  }
];
```

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect  } from 'react';
import NoteItem from './NoteItem';
import LeadContext from '../../context/Lead/leadContext';

const Notes = () => {
  const leadContext = useContext(LeadContext);
  const { lead } = leadContext;


  return (
    <div className='leadul'>
     {lead.notes.map((note => <NoteItem key={note.id} note={note}/>))} 
    </div>
  );
}

export default Notes;
```

```
{notes: Array(1), tasks: Array(0), createdate: "2020-02-19T23:25:11.033Z", claimedBy: "unclaimed", isClaimed: false, …}
notes: [{…}]
tasks: []
createdate: "2020-02-19T23:25:11.033Z"
claimedBy: "unclaimed"
isClaimed: false
isClosed: false
isPaid: false
isApproved: false
name2: ""
address2: ""
city2: ""
state2: ""
zip2: ""
employerTime: ""
ssn2: ""
lexId2: ""
relation: ""
phone2: ""
phone3: ""
email2: ""
email3: ""
prac: ""
problem1: ""
problem2: ""
problem3: ""
resSold: ""
resSold2: ""
home: ""
homePay: ""
wages: ""
income1Type: ""
income1Value: ""
income2Type: ""
income2Value: ""
income3Type: ""
income3Value: ""
otherIncomeType: ""
otherIncomeValue: ""
availableCredit: ""
totalCredit: ""
employerName: ""
employerPhone: ""
_id: "5e4dc4354b3bcd36ec86fd53"
notePostedBy: "5e3b346d572df30017a39ef7"
name: "xxxxx"
address: "xxxxx"
city: "xxxxxx"
state: "xxxxx"
zip: "xxxxx"
plaintiff: "STATE OF WEST VIRGINIA"
amount: "10144"
lexId: ""
compliant: "filed"
filingStatus: "m"
cpa: "cpa"
ssn: ""
createdBy: "5e3b346d572df30017a39ef7"
__v: 0
__proto__: Object
```

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
Notes
C:/Webdev/ntenet/client/src/components/popkis/Notes.js:13
  10 | 
  11 |  
  12 | return (
> 13 |   <div className='leadul'>
  14 |    {lead.notes.map((note => <NoteItem key={note.id} note={note}/>))} 
  15 |   </div>
  16 |   );
```

Comment: Are you fetching the lead object from an API? It looks like you are fetching it and your component renders before the lead object has the notes assigned to it. Can you console log the lead object? It looks like it has no notes (at least on first render).

Comment: lead does come from my back end but the note is there like when i take the map out and look at console.log(lead.notes) there it is

Comment: Are you sure it is there from the beginning? It might be `undefined` for the first render and after the second render become an object but then the error got already thrown. I replied in an answer.

Comment: @MickeyGray Not sure what the reason is yet, but it's sure the `notes` property is not set when it hits that point in the code. Unfortunately it's hard to see from the snippets how that comes about. Maybe there is some more code to include here. Also try logging the value of `lead` just before the `return` statement that renders the page.

Answer (score 0):

When you are fetching data from an API, you have to make sure that the components that rely on the data do not render before the API data has been successfully loaded into the context. There are several ways to do so.

The easiest would be something like this:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect  } from 'react';
import NoteItem from './NoteItem';
import LeadContext from '../../context/Lead/leadContext';

const Notes = () => {
  const leadContext = useContext(LeadContext);
  const { lead } = leadContext;


  return (
    <>
    { lead.notes
      ?
        <div className='leadul'>
         {lead.notes.map((note => <NoteItem key={note.id} note={note}/>))} 
        </div>
      : 
        <p>Data is still loading! Show a nice loading icon here</p>
    }
    </>
  );
}

export default Notes;
```

Comment: Both solutions worked, Theres gonna be more questions about this element, look out.

Answer (score 0):

when rending your component react has not gotten any data and the view is already rendered yous a conditional statement there eg

```
 return (
    <div className='leadul'>
      {
        lead && lead.notes ? 
         lead.notes.map(note => (
           <NoteItem 
            key={note.id} 
            note={note}
           />
          )
         ) : <></>
       } 
     </div>
 );
```